# EF Core - Connection string on private local database

Tags: c#, entity-framework, azure

**Connection string on private database with (EF Core)**

We have the API services install on Azure and working good with database on Azure server.

But we have BIG problem with some customers they can not opens database port on internet and customer database setup on LOCAL server because they have some issue on pci compliance & pci rule **(cannot have the sql db connected directly to the internet)**
and also they can't move from local database to azure database server.

**Questions** 
How we can resolve on this problem / any good solution ? if we can't USE IP-Address database server on "appsettings.jason"

Best

Answer (score 0):

You may create a Azure Hybrid connection to connect to the Local (on premise) database.

Using Hybrid connection you can directly connet to local database from API Services on Azure.

Here is an [overview on Azure Hybrid connection](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/biztalk-services/integration-hybrid-connection-overview)

Documentation for [creating and managing Hybrid connection](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/biztalk-services/integration-hybrid-connection-create-manage)

Comment: Thanks you so much.